# Visual Studio 2008 XML Documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xml-comments

I can't seem to find the "Build" option under "Configuration Properties" folder in the Property Pages of my project. I've been looking everywhere trying to figure out how to do it.

I followed the direations here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx

More specifically here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azt1z1eh.aspx
("To build the XML Documentation sample within Visual Studio" section)

I want to generate XML comments for my project in the build, but my "Configuration Properties" window does not have "folders" or a "Build" option under it.

I'm using Visual Studio Team System 2008, any ideas?

EDIT -> This is a website [project-less] and it is written in both C# and VB.NET.

Do I need to download any tools? I found GhostDoc but that's not helping me very much.

Comment: Please specify the type of project (ie: web site, web app, class lib)

Comment: It is a Web Site Project

Comment: Web Sites are not Projects. In general, if documentation applies to projects, then it does not apply to web sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by the "Configuration Properties" folder. I don't have anything like that - if I just double click on "Properties" under the project (in Solution Explorer), it comes up with the properties page which has the following tabs (for a console app in VS 2008 Pro):

- Application
- Build
- Build events
- Debug
- Resources
- Services
- Settings
- Reference Paths
- Signing
- Security
- Publish

Does this sound anything like the screen you're looking at? Can you grab a screenshot of what you've got?

If you just double click on "Properties" what do you get?

Comment: I should note that I am building a website. I have a "Website" menu instead of a "Project" menu, and in the solution explorer I also have a "website"- if I right-click it, I have "Property Pages" as a choice with the options:

References
Build
Accessibility
Start Options
MS Build Options

Comment: Ah. That's almost certainly it. It doesn't really make much sense to generate XML documentation for a website. What would you use it for? Create a class library which you refer to from your web site and build the XML documentation for the class library. That will be useful when you reuse the library

Answer (score 1):

Are you using C# or VB.NET?  In VB.NET, the Properties pages look a bit different.  There is a checkbox on the Compile property page that states "Generate XML documentation file".  Make sure it's checked.

Comment: The website project was developed both in C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I have a webservice that I'd like to create this kind of documentation for. It's also a website project, so I don't have the menu. Has a solution been found for this situation?

Comment: Yes. Don't ever use a web site "project" for anything other than a web site; and then, only if it's a simple web site, being developed by staff who are less technical.

Answer (score 0):

right click of any class library of your project and select properties then you will find Build tab option... there you can specify the xml documentation file path. -ibrahim

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN magazine article you reference is out of date. The link to the 2008 and 2010 documentation has been updated and gives the proper directions.

Turn on XML comments by choosing **Project | Properties** from the menu and turning to the **Build** page. You might note that with many monitors, you will have to scroll down on the **Build** page before finding the section on XML comments.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to be able to build docs for a webservice (a website project) since it will be consumed by a third party.  The XML docs can be consumed by the web service caller via wsdl using the [wcfextras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) flow.  Does this mean I must break out my solution consisting of just two .cs file into a separate project in order just to get the doc or is there another way?  Thanks.